# What does the "Incoming" option refer to in ufw?

Tags: firewall, ufw

I am configuring a firewall on my Linux Mint 17.2 to maximize security, mainly to put my mind at rest that no one will be able to do anything malicious. In `gufw`, there are options for allowing or blocking incoming or outgoing. By denying incoming, what kinds of communications am I blocking? In other words, what does incoming refer to? (And out of curiosity, what does outgoing refer to?) I assume that incoming is when another computer attempts to connect to you in some manner, while outgoing is just the opposite - when you attempt to connect to another computer. However, I am not sure, so I would appreciate an answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Incoming connections are connections from the outside made to your computer, these are the types of connection requests that can indeed be malicious, and denying incoming connections is the right thing to do unless you are opening a specific port for a specific application that needs to allow these incoming connections.

The short answer is: Outgoing packets are packets that originated on your system; requests sent from you to some other (usually server) computer, and incoming packets are packets that originated on somebody else's computer; requests sent from somebody else to your computer (and can often be malicious or hacking attempts).

To simplify this greatly, when you send out a connection request, like say try to connect to a website, you are sending a request that will appear as "incoming" on the web server you are connecting to and if the connection is accepted, data will be transmitted back to you as per your connection request (e.g. you are allowed access). From your computer this entire process is an outgoing request. And can be done without your computer accepting incoming requests.

Now lets say you have a server, a server of any kind (a website, a game server, a voip server...) now when you set that up, lets say that you have incoming connections blocked, what this means is that no external computer can connect to your server, but if you open the port the server wants to use for incoming connections, that port will be tied to this server, so any incoming connections made to that port will be redirected to your server application which will then feed it a response (send it back data/grant it access).

To put this in perspective, lets say someone connects to your computer via remote desktop. This must be done through a port on your system that is open to incoming connections or else they won't be able to connect. And the same of course applies to Remote Administration Tools (RAT; A common type of virus used for all kinds of nefarious purposes, including the creation of botnets).

Now I'm not quite saying that it's impossible to use outgoing traffic to do the same, once access has been gained to your computer it certainly might not be so hard to set things up so that your computer sends outgoing signals to a specific address/server and another's accesses that address/server to receive the output and somehow send back response data that through a program on your computer somehow controls or affects your PC. But for this to happen if all incoming connections are closed, your computer would have to be infected first for this to be possible (i.e. it can't, or at least not as easily be just "hacked" into, and many basic viruses can be stopped just by closing down incoming ports)

So disabling incoming connections basically locks down your vulnerability to targeted hacking but you remain vulnerable to downloaded viruses like spyware that will after being downloaded on to your system and executed transmit data from your system outwards.

As for outgoing packets; lets say you have spyware and it transmits data from your compute to someone elses (or grants them access to it). Trying to block it might be pretty futile since we need outgoing connections to connect to HTTP anyways, and they could in many cases communicate such data via HTTP to begin with (so you'd basically have to block your internet completely), and that is why the answer is: Lock down incoming network ports wherever possible, and pray you don't get infected by crap. It  doesn't hurt to try blocking all unused outgoing ports as well though, but it might cause you some pains (e.g. programs not working until you find out what ports needs to be forward it; unless you don't use very many programs that connect to the net) it would at least slightly limit the collection of malware that could successfully send outgoing data from your computer if it ever got in.

You can safely block all incoming connections without worrying about your internet not working afterwards, very few applications require ports to be open for incoming connections (most who do are server applications, and applications that want you to upload data, like say torrent applications) and when the need arises, it is considered safe to open up incoming connections on specific ports as demand rises in your system as long as the application requiring it is trustworthy (since basically all incoming requests sent to through that port will be directed to the application, and only through holes in the application could it ever cause harm to your computer or directly access it instead of just being confined to this application)

This is sadly the extent of my own understanding (not exactly a networker) but to ever understand the answer to your question,k you're basically just going to have to understand the basics of how firewalls work.

This explanation is as good as any: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N2sOPGhva1M

And also let me cross reference [the same question on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/443038/what-does-incoming-and-outgoing-traffic-mean).